# Is it good practice to put database connections into a class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, libraries, entity-framework

I am using entity framework and I created multiple libs. XYZ is main lib which handles majority of operations. And for integration purpose I have created different libs which are comparatively smaller.

I want them to have database connection of external account table which handles authentication and token management. In XYZ I have crated entity class for database access, but I don't want to reference XYZ into smaller lib because I just want to use one class and that will create unnecessary burden.

What is a recommended way to provide database connection for single table?

Should I create same entity class in every lib or create new lib to access database?

Comment: Why is referencing the main library a burden?

Comment: Because its too large, and I think just to access one table I should not reference whole lib..

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251195/is-it-good-practice-to-put-database-connections-into-a-class-library

Comment: Entity Framework DBContext classes are designed to be as lightweight as possible.  Use the entire DBContext; it's intended to be used that way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you post some link or example.. please.

Comment: It's just the usual usage; there are tons of examples already out there.  You new up your DbContext object, and reference the table.  You already know how to do it.  Have a look here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Is this what you're getting at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Seems like your login class belongs into a third library that would be referenced by both: the main XYZ and your other smaller libraries.

Libraries are like bricks that contain common functionalities. If you feel like you are referencing a library for just one little bit of it, **move the bit out, it's obviously common between other libraries as well**. Then reference it from all the libraries that require it.

**Current:**

```
Library A -> Library XYZ(Which contains login stuff)
```

**New Solution:**

```
Library A -> Login Library
Library XYZ -> Login Library
```

Comment: :-- I understand that, but that will be lot of restructuring in main program.. I suggested that idea to my seniors.. but they dont want to do all that hard work and not want to take that risk.... lols..   any ways thanks

Comment: Then just reference the main library. Code duplication is never a good way.

Comment: This may be true for almost any functionality, however, for security, it may be risky. If someone copies that dll, she may get access to the system. This is probably a very remote possibility anyway.

Comment: @EmmadKareem that can be happen with any dll ... Even if he able to copy main dll then he has access to all functions... but database is secure... connection string is in app config folder.. and database is tightly coupled and dependent on other values... but its good suggestion thanks